# How can I only enable an redux-observable epic to continue only when another epic is not running

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I am basically looking to have epics:

1. Epic A - When REQUEST_A comes in, emit action EPIC_A_STARTED, after some indeterminate time (async action) emit action EPIC_A_END
2. Epic B - When REQUEST_B comes in, If Epic A has not started continue, Else wait until EPIC_A_END is completed.

Ideally both epics when run will wait for their alternative to complete, so only one occurs at a time.

It feels like I need a counter to increment when EPIC_A_STARTED occurs and decrement when EPIC_A_COMPLETED occurs, but I am not really sure how to proceed.

It would be nice if we could have an operator something like this psuedo code:

```
// Operator we are trying to write
const waitForActionsToComplete = (startAction, endAction) => {
   // Not sure how to structure this so that it waits for there to be equal of both actions passing through
}


// Epic A
const EPIC_A_FILTER = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    of(actions.REQUEST_A),
    waitForActionsToComplete(actions.EPIC_B_START, actions.EPIC_B_END),
    mergeMap(() => { type: actions.EPIC_A_START }));

const EPIC_A_PROCESS = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    of(actions.EPIC_A_START),
    ...async task,
    mergeMap(() => { type: actions.EPIC_A_END }));


// Epic B
const EPIC_B_FILTER = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    of(actions.REQUEST_B),
    waitForActionsToComplete(actions.EPIC_A_START, actions.EPIC_A_END),
    mergeMap(() => { type: actions.EPIC_B_START }));

const EPIC_B_PROCESS = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    of(actions.EPIC_B_START),
    ...async task,
    mergeMap(() => { type: actions.EPIC_B_END }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scan` to queue the request start actions, and only de-queue after an epic end action. I've written something psuedo-codeish:

```
action$.pipe(
    of(actions.REQUEST_A, actions.REQUEST_B, actions.EPIC_A_END, actions.EPIC_B_END),
    scan(({queue}, current) => {
      if (current is epic end action)
        if (queue is not empty) {
          return { queue: queue.slice(1), triggerEpic: EPIC_A_START or EPIC_B_START depending on queue[0]  }
        }
        else {
          return { queue, triggerEpic: null };
        }
      }
      else {
        if (queue is not empty) {     
          return { queue: [...queue, current], triggerEpic: null };
        }
        else {
          return { queue: [], triggerEpic: EPIC_A_START or EPIC_B_START depending on current }; 
        } 
      } 
    }, { queue: [], triggerEpic: null }),
    filter(x => x.triggerEpic !== null),
    map(x => x.triggerEpic)
)
```